# Hive ODBC Driver creation with Advance option

Tags: c#, hive, odbc

We are creating DSN using C# code using below link
[How do I create an ODBC DSN entry using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334939/how-do-i-create-an-odbc-dsn-entry-using-c)

We want to set server side properties available in Advance options button by adding key and value. we tried by adding below code, dsnKey.SetValue("hive.vectorized.execution.enabled", "1"); dsnKey.SetValue("hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled", "1");

However it is not working.

Please help me fro the the same.

Answer (score 0):

dsnKey.SetValue("SSP_hive.vectorized.execution.enabled", "true");
dsnKey.SetValue("SSP_hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled", "true");